# Search Result Block with Custom Managed Properties

Tags: 2013, search, display-template

I have a query rule that triggers the display of a result block. I have a couple custom managed properties I'd like to display in the result block, but they always show up empty in my display template.

I followed Bella's [wonderful entry](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/12/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-2.aspx) and was able to get the custom managed properties to show in ranked search results, but if I use the exact same item template inside a result block, the values are empty.

I've included my fields in the ManagedPropertyMapping field of my item template, and I have confirmed that the managed properties have been created successfully, as I can see their values when hitting the search API directly.

I have a hunch that for some reason, when using an item template inside a result block, that it does't pay attention to the custom properties in the ManagedPropertyMapping tag.

So finally my question.... Has anyone been able to display a custom managed property inside a **result block?**

Much appreciated,

Comment: I have the same problem.